# Adding value to a Dictionary in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

In the below code am using `Parallel.ForEach` to get the data of each item in my collection and store the response in the dictionary. But, in the dictionary the key and values are mismatched. Response of 1st item, is stored in the name of 2nd Item or 3rd item name.

```cs
Dictionary<string, object> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Parallel.ForEach(myCollection, item =>
{
    var data = GetData(item);
    if (!keyValues.ContainsKey(item))
    {
        keyValues.Add(item, data);
    }
});
return keyValues;
```

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add` is not thread-safe. You could use a `ConcurrentDictionary`, or just use a standard `foreach`. Is `GetData` computationally expensive enough to warrant multithreading?

Comment: Did you mean `if (!keyValues.ContainsKey(item))`?  Regardless, `ConcurrentDictionary` has `GetOrAdd` or `TryAdd` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0), because  `Dictionary` isn't thread-safe.

Replace the `ContainsKey` and `Add` method calls with `TryAdd`